# jQuery - find a element inside a another element and getting it's html content

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

so a Ajax call will return some data as html.

I'm creating a element from this data with  `var comment = $("<ul />").html(data);`

Now I want to get the html content from another element inside the `comment` element I just created above.
I'm using `var commentbody = comment.find(".comment-body").html();`

This works, but the problem is that I get the element's contents only. I want to get the element tags too.

How can I do that?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need its HTML string?

Comment: @patrick dw: because I want to separate the code from the comment template. If I would get only the comment content text I would have to hardcode my own comment template in the javascript (or a part of it). Initially I wanted to replace the entire list item, but comments can have child comments so that would not work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var commentbody = comment.find(".comment-body");

var outerHTML = commentbody[0].outerHTML || 
                          commentbody.clone().appendTo('<div>').parent().html();
```

Here you first find the `.comment-body` element you want. Then you access the DOM element with `[0]` and get its `outerHTML` property.

If it doesn't have an `outerHTML` property, then make a [`clone()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) of it, [`appendTo()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) a new `<div>`, traverse up to the [`parent()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) `<div>` and get its [`html()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/html/) content.

This answer assumes there's only *one* `.comment-body` to be found.